# Suitescript adds .0 to numbers in array

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

In Suitescript 2.0 I want to check if an ID does not match with one of the IDs in the array below:

```
var interfaceStatusArray1 = [14, 15, 17, 20, 25, 26];
```

In the debugger I see that .0 is added to every value in the array :

[image]

Now if my ID is 1 and I do the following check:

```
 interfaceStatusArray1.indexOf(lineItemFieldValues.interfaceStatusID) == -1
```

then this will always be true, because the numbers have .0 added.

Is there a way to remove the .0? I already tried Math.trunc, but Netsuite gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function trunc in object [object Math].
```

I also reproduced the code in jsfiddle however in jsfiddle it works, because it gets into false:
https://jsfiddle.net/7fnxoz1r/1/

I am quite new to Suitescript 2.0 but it also seems that suitescript 2.0 does not allow array.includes.

Comment: You could use `Math.floor()` but may not need to; `1 === 1.0` is true.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks. I also tried if(1 === 1.0) and this gives true. But whenever I try the code in the question (without Math..) it is not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set interfaceStatusArray1 as a string array? If needed you can turn them to number back/forward using the primitive classes String(val)/Number(val)

Comment: Tried different approaches but for now this also seems the most easiest to execute, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not unique to NetSuite but is how JavaScript handles numbers: there are only numbers, not integers and floating point, so all numbers in JS are basically floating point.  If you need to consume these as a number, the fact the ".0" is displayed won't matter.  Indeed, if you ToString() them, the ".0" won't be in the string.

To use your example:

```
interfaceStatusArray1.indexOf(lineItemFieldValues.interfaceStatusID) == -1
```

If lineItemFieldValues.interfaceStatusID is 1.0, JavaScript would say the condition is false (1.0 !== -1.0).  If you want to be sure, use "===" instead of "==" and add the ".0" in your condition.